# ProjectReference in SDK-style project ignores Condition for transitive dependencies

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild

I have a solution, consisting of 3 projects

- `_TestSDK` - main project (SDK-style, net48)
- `TestTool` - library project (non-SDK-style, net FW4.8)
- `PSWrapper` - library project (non-SDK-style, net FW4.8)

Ready-to-use solution may be found here: https://github.com/snechaev/sdk-style-project-ref/tree/master

Dependencies are following

- `_TestSDK` references `TestTool`
- `TestTool` *conditionally* references `PSWrapper` (only for `DebugJS` build configuration)

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\PSWrapper\PSWrapper.csproj"
    Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='DebugJS'">
  <Project>{1675096e-bf7b-486b-89f9-dfe147418dbc}</Project>
  <Name>PSWrapper</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

Additionally, in the Configuration manager, the `PSWrapper` project is configured to be built only in `DebugJS` configuration.

The problem is that I can't build `_TestSDK` project in a `Release` configuration in Visual studio 2019 (16.10.2). I got an error

```
2>CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 
'D:\project\PSWrapper\bin\Release\PSWrapper.dll' could not be found
```

Although in `Release` configuration the `PSWrapper` project should not be used in any way as it is restricted by only `DebugJS` configuration by the `Condition` attribute.

If I build `PSWrapper` manually and then try to build `_TestSDK` again, the build will succeed, but in the output directory there will be `PSWrapper.dll`, which should not be there for `Release` configuration.

I created old-style project `_TestFW`, which is just references `TestTool` project (exactly as `_TestSDK` does). And for the `_TestFW` all works fine.

So, the question is: is it a way to force sdk-style project to respect `Condition` attribute for transitive references?

Note: converting `TestTool` & `PSWrapper` projects to sdk-style is not an option for now.